# Haze correction of Planet SkySat Public Ortho Imagery, RGB

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, atmospheric-correction

I am using image - https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/SKYSAT_GEN-A_PUBLIC_ORTHO_RGB for slum quantification purpose but the problem is - the image seem to have haze as image resolution is 0.8 but does not seem to look. Is it possible to correct haze in Google Earth Engine?

The code is:

```js
var center = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([85.32049578835093, 27.687596070113184]),
    AOI = 
    /* color: #0b4a8b */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[85.3055106807987, 27.699781579655742],
          [85.3055106807987, 27.671812169751316],
          [85.34430615199011, 27.671812169751316],
          [85.34430615199011, 27.699781579655742]]], null, false);

Map.centerObject(center,16)

var d1 = ee.ImageCollection('SKYSAT/GEN-A/PUBLIC/ORTHO/RGB').median().clip(AOI);
print(ee.ImageCollection('SKYSAT/GEN-A/PUBLIC/ORTHO/RGB'),"Image Collection")
print(d1,"D1")
Map.addLayer(d1,{ min: 25.62, max: 129.33,gamma:0.96}, 'D1(RGB)');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f2cc1bec8edc55bfa4efbff73a32f25e

The point is in the slum which needs to be visible for the classification and analysis purpose.

Comment: Looks clear to me. Resolution is definitely 0.8m, I measured it https://code.earthengine.google.com/eb7a899d0dcc9aacd86c4db364e1a367

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks. May be it's a slum and current resolution is not able to visualize clearly.